# Oddly popular typo-based question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, typographical-error

I came across [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/30033384/error-injectoritkn-incorrect-injection-token-expected-service-name-as-stri) the other day. The question is about a simple typographical error, answered by the OP.  It struck me as odd because despite its nature it hasn't been closed after a year and a half and the question and answer have garnered an unusually high number of upvotes for a typo resolution.

So I'm wondering, is there some context to this question, only obvious to a niche set of users, that explains the popularity of this question?

I took the obvious step of raising a "simple typographical error" flag to allow users with mod privileges to determine if it should be closed, but the flag aged away.

Comment: Ironical [op](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan) is currently suspended for voting irregularities.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar: Not sure if that's *ironic* as much as telling.

Comment: It is the second Google hit for "incorrect injection token".  The first hit is the official Angular doc for this error, it doesn't cover the OP's specific mistake explicitly.  It is an awfully lousy error message and the official docs are technobabble, popularity is practically guaranteed.  So it isn't exactly about a typo, it is about an inscrutable error message.  Looks like it is heading for deletion, maybe not so likely to make the Internet better.

Comment: @HansPassant So do you think it could be edited and salvaged? Possibly fit for the new documentation section?

Comment: Editing a very popular post is risky, the magic that made it the #2 Google hit isn't always obvious.  It could be undeleted, if necessary.

Comment: This seems to be exactly why typo questions shouldn't be dismissed as bad questions so quickly. I don't get the mania to declear typos so completely unuseful that they must be deleted on sight.

Comment: @HansPassant In this case the question may have reached #2 on Google by being older than similar questions.  It might be a post of merit to the angular community but less than ideally conveyed.  The question was closed rather quickly after being put on hold. Isn't there a grace period to allow for constructive editing, or does that only apply to specific close reasons?

Comment: Wow, 19 downvotes and deletion in a day thanks to the Meta effect. I won't pretend this was a great question, but worse ones - both in the sense of being less coherent/answerable, and of being less useful to future visitors - are asked every day without receiving downvotes. The only reason this one ever came to the downvoters' attention was that it *was useful to so many people* that it stood out. Now, as a consequence of its (admittedly surprising) usefulness, it's been clobbered. Good job, Meta! That'll teach the rep-whoring bastard not to get upvotes in unfair ways, like by helping people.

Comment: There's some good points made here for preserving the question. Surprisingly there's not any commentary so far from the those who opted to delete the question.

Comment: @faintsignal if you post a link to meta, it will be up,down,close,delete,and un*voted in any order, regardless of context and content.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the question at hand is old, ranks highly on Google, and has a highly upvoted answer, I would bet that those upvotes aren't from the SO regulars who saw it in the first few minutes of its creation, but rather from visitors who had that same problem, Googled it, and found a resolution for their issue. As @HansPassant mentions [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339722/oddly-popular-typo-based-question?cb=1#comment422305_339722), it may be a typo, but the normal way to troubleshoot a problem - the error message - is ineffective here. The root cause of the problem (a typo) may be off-topic for SO, but the reality of the situation turns it into an issue that is difficult to solve through normal means.

Python has a similar question, [Strange invalid synthax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440558/strange-invalid-syntax-error)<sup>1</sup>. It is "strange" because the traceback points to a line with no apparent problems. It causes an error because it's not a syntactically valid continuation *of the previous line*, which is not displayed in the error message. The interpreter is expecting it to be a valid continuation of the previous line because that previous line lacks a final closing parenthesis, a common typo.

I use that as a duplicate target almost every day, because it can be difficult to tell

```
... ('.')[2])-1]))]
                  ^
```

from

```
... ('.')[2])-1]))
                  ^
```

and anyone unaware of this little quirk will be expecting a useful traceback (as Python usually provides).

However, the traceback will be a `SyntaxError` pointing at whatever the next line is, which could be perfectly valid if it was seen as a single line rather than a continuation of the previous one. If a user searches SO for errors with the indicated line, Google will come up with nothing. So they ask a new question. Hopefully the code they post includes the line before the one indicated in the traceback, so that we can see the missing bracket and confirm the cause of the problem.

If this "missing comma" question is as common as "missing closing parenthesis/bracket/brace on previous line," it *will* be asked again, and again, and again... and it'll take five privileged users to close it as a typo rather than a single gold-badge user to do what I do:

Hammer it as a duplicate.

With a duplicate closure, the asker gets a solution, the matter is closed, and the question can be deleted as soon as it meets the various criteria.

The "typo" close reason, on the other hand, is very generic. Closing a question in that fashion pretty much requires a brief answer in the comments (assuming you want to actually resolve the asker's issue). If that specific problem is common enough to have appeared in multiple questions, it's more convenient for privileged users and more helpful for the asker if it's closed as a specific duplicate. If the new question is bad (as typo questions generally are), it can be deleted in the same way that the question at hand was.

But please, leave one alive, even if it's only to make it easier to kill the rest.

<sup>1</sup>Sad update: that syntax error question was deleted a few days ago. I've switched to [SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Very simple one..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760684/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-very-simple-one) instead.

Comment: In other words, don't tear down the lightning rod.

Comment: It bears pointing out that the *real* purpose of the "typo" close reason is to better capture the true purpose of the old "too localized" close reason. In other words, **you only close "typo" questions if their answers will never be useful to anyone else in the future**. Clearly, in this case, that is not true. This is a special kind of typo, one that programmers make often, and thus the question is quite useful. Closing it is perverse, since it is not off-topic for any other reason.

Comment: Another example (one that I keep referring to whenever the topic of typo questions gets brought up): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877198/why-is-rgb-224-226-213-an-invalid-property-value

Comment: It's been closed and deleted now, I voted to undelete the question. I think closing it might be appropriate, but the deletion was a bad call.

Comment: [The timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30033384/timeline) would appear to agree with the idea that it was slowly upvoted over the months because it was useful.

Comment: @KevinBrown Indeed: "21 hours ago  votes  daily summary  N/A  Up: 1 Down: 17" To me, this is exactly what's wrong with Meta and its community. This is a question that did not get any answer from SO for two weeks, until the OP himself found the problem, shared it with the community, and apparently ended up helping others. That's a very nice thing done by that OP, when he was under no obligation whatsoever to do so, and the Meta community saw it fit to just piss all over it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: It doesn't help that the part of the close reason description that's in **bold** is the part that says "**a simple typographical error**", and not "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".

Comment: Agreed, @BoltClock. I would change the bolding of several of the off-topic reasons if it was within my control. "Why isn't this code working" is not the part we want to emphasize, so much as "must include the desired behavior ... and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it".